# c++ #include (what functions are in what)

Tags: c++, c, include

I am a fairly seasoned Java programmer, so i understand what including does, and why to do it, BUT, I am using java for a example, When i need a method i can go to the structure and open the jars and see what is there, but i have been watching some tut's and they say you are going to need to include this .h file because it has this function etc, So the question: I typed #include<.h> and got a list of all the .h files, but NOWHERE do i see what is in those files, so if i need to use a function that gets to the system properties(Just a example), how do you know what to include, I am really not liking C right now for this only reason.

Comment: Have you tried reading the fine manual documenting the function you want to use? Normally, it would specify the header you need to #include   for it.

Comment: For C++, just go to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/) search the function you need, for ex [for_each](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each), and you'll get the header.

Comment: Both the C and C++ standards define not only their languages and behaviors, they also define standard-mandated (and some optional) library functionality, including which header is required to access it. Some *fantastic* websites have made searching this a snap (such as [cppreference](http://www.cppreference.com)). For other functionality provided by 3rd party libraries they should document similarly.

Comment: Thanks Guys, I guess i was spoiled from the javadoc in java I didnt know about cppreference.

Comment: Removing `[java]` tag given the answer is not expected to be about Java.

Answer (score 2):

functions do not exist in a header file (.h). They exist in .lib, .so, .dll etc files depending on whether they are static or dynamic and depending on the operating system. The header file just declares/prototypes the function. Typically the documentation of a function tells you which header it's declared in.

Header files are text files. You can open them in any text editor to see them, to see what functions they declare.

Typically, if the documentation doesn't tell me the header (rare), I go to the headers directory and either do a `grep` (on Linux/Unixes) or a `findstr` on windows to figure out where the function I want is declared.

Another thing to know is that including the right header file will help in compilation of your program but may not ensure that your program will link to build the final binary. For that you link with the right lib file. Again the documentation of the function will tell which is the right lib to link with. In the microsoft world, some header files may have a `pragma` lib entry which ensures that including the header automatically links in the right lib file.

A lot of the documentation is also available online - msdn, cppreference etc.

Comment: All source files are text files.